# How to use hidden HTML value in function call?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a student working on a website that quizzes users about which jazz artist is playing on a recording. I randomized all the recordings and the placement of the correct answer. I made an HTML hidden value and assigned a previously made JavaScript variable to it. However, when I try to send it in to check the answer for the question, it says that all the answers are incorrect. I figured out how to assign the value between the two languages but I cannot find anything about using it in a function call where I can't call the id.

```
<input type="hidden" id="answer" value="">
<script>
    document.getElementById("answer").value=correct;
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="checkAnswer('answer')" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: can you post your full html and script? it's difficult to guess what you want to achieve here

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]